# Can't connect to local Raspberry IP from Linux Mint PC (trying to set up Audiobookshelf)

Tags: docker

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/host-raspberry-pi-audiobook-library-audiobookshelf/) trying to set up Audiobookshelf.

I'm at the step `Setting Up Audiobookshelf From Your Home Network`

everything else has worked fine. I did the whole process via SSH from my Linux Mint PC, which worked surprisingly well (don't have much experience with this). As far as I can tell, I successfully installed Audiobookshelf in a Docker.

But now I can't seem to connect to the RasPi's local IP address. I do `hostname -I` still in SSH and get several numbers. One of them starts with `192` so I put that into the browser on my Mint PC, followed by the port `:13378`.

And then it either just tells me right away that it is `Unable to connect`, or once or twice it tells me that it can't connect securely (via `https`) but I could connect via `http`, but when I click yes, it just times out too.

Any advice appreciated!

I'm not interested connecting it to the internet, so I really just want to connect to it locally, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Edit: I imagine I've found the issue, but don't know how to solve it:

```
docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
05a952677529   ghcr.io/advplyr/audiobookshelf:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Exited (133) 2 minutes ago             username_audiobookshelf_1
```

If I'm reading that right, it exits right when I launch it.

Why is that? Or rather, how do I find out why? And would dockers usually start on their own on launch? Or do I have to manually launch it via SSH every time?